# CSS won't load using Flask

Tags: python, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flask

I built my backend using Python Flask and tested it with basic HTML templates with no CSS and it worked no problem. However, when I tried to implement Bootstrap it won't load the css. I've placed the css and js files into a static folder.

Here is the Bootstrap HTML markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head     content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Simple Safety</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="{{ url_for('static', filename ='bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <link href="{{ url_for('static', filename =ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="{{ url_for('static', filename ='style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy these 2 lines! -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename = 'ie-emulation-modes-warning.js') }}"></script>-->

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js">    </script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js">    </script>
    <![endif]-->
    </head>

<!--Main Content-->

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="{{url_for('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/', filename='jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write("<script type='text/javascript' src='{{ url_for('static', filename='jquery.min.js') }}''><\/script>")</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename ='bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js') }}"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

I realized that I had placed my 'static' folder in the 'templates' folder, an old habit I did with front-end only applications. You need to place the 'static' folder in the directory with the templates folder.